# Time Complexity for $T\left(n\right)\:=\:T\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\:+\:n^2$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence relation to solve :

$T\left(n\right)\:=\:T\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\:+\:n^2$

I have tried the following:

let $2^m = n$

$T\left(2^m\right)\:=\:T\left(2^{\frac{m}{2}}\right)\:+\:\left(2^m\right)^2$

$F\left(m\right)\:=\:F\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\:+\:m^2$

At this point I thought it is the third case of master theorem but I think I'm wrong.

Comment: You write $n=2^m$ but then substitute $n=2m$. Also later you write $2^{m^2}$ but this is not what $n^2$ equals for $n=2^m$.

Comment: @Snaw Sorry I meant $\left(2^m\right)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$ T(n) = T(\sqrt n) + n^{2} $$
then you can substitute $\sqrt n$ for $n$:
$$ T(\sqrt n) = T(\sqrt  (\sqrt n)) + n. $$
So this yields
$$ T(n) = n^{2} + n + \sqrt n + n^{\frac{1}{4}} + ... + T(n^{\frac{1}{c}}). $$
As $c$ approaches infinity, $n^{\frac{1}{c}}$ approaches 1. Therefore

$$ T(n) = T(1) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n^{2^{1-k}}. $$
That is it, but now you should consider whether it converges or not and when. Also, consider when this formula is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Using the transformation $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right) = \mathcal{T}\left(\frac z2\right)+\left(2^z\right)^2
$$

Using analogously now $\mathbb{T}(\cdot) = \mathcal{T}\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $u=\log_2 z$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{T}\left(u\right)=\mathbb{T}\left(u-1\right)+ \left(2^{2^u}\right)^2
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb{T}\left(u\right)=c_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{u-1}2^{2^{k+2}}
$$

or going backwards with $u=\log_2 z$ and $z=\log_2 u$

$$
T(n) = c_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(\log_2 n)-1}2^{2^{k+2}}
$$

but

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(\log_2 n)-1}2^{2^{k+2}} = n^2+n+\sqrt{n}+\cdots+ n^{2^{-k}}+\cdots
$$

then $\mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)\le T(n) \lt \mathcal{O}\left(n^3\right)$